# why changing state does not trigger if it's related to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote some code to exercise in React. I would like somebody to explain me why if the target of the `clickChange` is clicked (h3), state does not update.

Below there is my main App component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Prova from "./components/prova";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "giovanni"
  };

  clickChange = () => {
    this.setState({ name: "joe" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>SONO APP</h3>
        <Prova onClick={this.clickChange} provaProp={this.state.name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Below another Component, imported and called (and rendered) into the main App component.
Now, as you can see i set up a method, `clickChange`, that, once you click on the  element, it SHOULD change the state, switching "giovanni" to "joe".

The question is: why it does not trigger? I know that the rendered part of the code it's in the other component, prova, but the state it's in my App component. Therefore, the state is changed internally, without any reference to the external.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Prova extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.provaProp}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Prova;
```

Comment: Enrico, if you ever get back to this, the short answer, which IMO has not been stated explicitly enough yet, is that `<Prova onClick={this.clickChange}` does *not* set a click handler but merely pass an unfortunately named *prop*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just forgot to trigger the `onClick` event inside your `Prova` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Prova extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <p>{this.props.provaProp}</p>         
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Prova;
```

demo

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "giovanni"
  };

  clickChange = () => {
    this.setState({ name: "joe" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>SONO APP</h3>
        <Prova onClick={this.clickChange} provaProp={this.state.name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Prova extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <p>{this.props.provaProp}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I'd go with, but it should mention that `onClick` doesn't work on its own when embedding Components in JSX. That's why I use `handleClick` for the prop, as opposed to the misleading `onClick`.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work due to this.onClick is not a function of child component

Comment: Change to `this.props.onClick` and it will work as expected.

Comment: @Tholle, even if he does that that still not going to change prop in `Prova` component.

Comment: @Infinity Yes, it definitely is: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yqwfgken/

Comment: @Tholle, my mistake, forgat the props word

Comment: @Infinity Yes it will. The state will change in the `App`, resulting in the props to `Prova` to change, which will make `Prova` re-render.

Comment: @Tholle, Gotcha. I think I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 4):

For props you will get it in `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Usage in child component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
  console.log(props.provaProps);
}
```

So whenever a state of parent component gets updated it updates the props as well but to get updated props in child components we use `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

See more [here](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html)

Additionally you forgot to attach click event in props

```
 <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
    <p>{this.props.provaProp}</p>         
 </div>
```

Comment: How is this related to OP's question?

Comment: @Tholle, Corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not tiggered `onClick` event in child Component.

change code in `Prova component` as

```
     <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <p>{this.props.provaProp}</p>
      </div>
```

resolved [react example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0q8r6qrllw)